# Preserve order by value when inserting to map

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, dictionary, tree

I need preserve order by value. I wrote some piece of code, but it is not really optimal.

I have a class like this,

```
class MyClass extends SomeOtherClass {

    private Map<Object, Object> resMap= new HashMap<>();

    Object getRes(Object key) {
        return resMap.get(key);
    }

    void putRes(Object key, Object value) {
        resMap.put(key, value);
    }
```

I want EACH time when I am invoking **putRes(Object value)** preserve order by value. 
Something like **if value (that I received as an input) > all other values in map** then put it first, if the value is equals to some value in map, so put it after it.

Appreciate any help.

upd: I need sort by Value and not by key. 
upd: I need sort by calling some method getPriority() of value.

Comment: Why can’t you use hash map?

Comment: I need preserve order while put in map by VALUE. If you have solution, I would be happy to see it)

Comment: How are you using the map after inserting values? Are you iterating over it?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

> A Map that further provides a total ordering on its keys. The map is
>   ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, **or by a
>   Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time.**